# ng add angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations => Schematics/alias "install" collides with another alias or schematic name

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

The command `ng add angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations` results in following error message:

> Your global Angular CLI version (8.3.1) is greater than your local
>   version (6.0.8). The local Angular CLI version is used.
>
> To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch
>   false".
>
> Installing packages for tooling via npm. Schematics/alias "install"
>   collides with another alias or schematic name. Error: Schematics/alias
>   "install" collides with another alias or schematic name.
>       at NodeModulesEngineHost.createCollectionDescription (D:\path\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\file-system-engine-host-base.js:125:27)
>       at SchematicEngine._createCollectionDescription (D:\path\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\engine.js:78:40)
>       at SchematicEngine.createCollection (D:\path\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\engine.js:71:43)
>       at Object.getCollection (D:\path\ClientApp\node_modules@angular\cli\utilities\schematics.js:28:31)
>       at AddCommand.getOptions (D:\path\ClientApp\node_modules@angular\cli\models\schematic-command.js:193:41)
>       at AddCommand. (D:\path\ClientApp\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\add.js:30:49)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at D:\path\ClientApp\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\add.js:7:71
>       at new Promise ()
>       at __awaiter (D:\path\ClientApp\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\add.js:3:12)

This is my package.json(after installing the above mentioned command):

```
    {
  "name": "PWA.web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run PWA.web:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/http": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.10",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "6.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

After updating the CLI, I get("Invalid rule result: Function()"), in the console:

> λ ng update @angular/cli Your global Angular CLI version (8.3.1) is
>   greater than your local version (6.0.8). The local Angular CLI version
>   is used.
>
> To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch
>   false".
>       packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed.
>       packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed. Ignoring.
>       Updating package.json with dependency @angular/cli @ "8.3.1" (was "6.0.8")... UPDATE package.json (1630 bytes)
>
> > @angular/cli@8.3.1 postinstall D:\path\ClientApp\node_modules@angular\cli
> >     node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
>
> npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.7 but none
>   is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4
>   (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted
>   {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> added 157 packages from 125 contributors, removed 5 packages, updated
>   5 packages and audited 17353 packages in 66.365s found 238
>   vulnerabilities (2 low, 14 moderate, 222 high)   run `npm audit fix`
>   to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
>       ** Executing migrations for package '@angular/cli' ** Invalid rule result: Function().

After executing `ng add angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations` again, it shows no error in the console, but when I start the project I get `[error] Error: Could not find the implementation for builder @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server` written on the webpage.

Find complete error log here:

https://shrib.com/#V8wxfbAihcJi8Nszax7L

Using asp.net core 2.2, what to do here?

Comment: Could you try to update your angular-cli version?

Comment: Where do you get the new error?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Angular-CLI 6.0.8 (https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12362).

Update to Angular-CLI 6.1 to fix this:

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

For the second issue you are facing, you could try:

1. Make sure your angular version starts with 7.2.15 (if not, you should install this version first)
2. Be sure your Node version is 12.x.x
3. Typescript version 3.4.5
4. ng update @angular/cli @angular/core (for @angular/cli, be sure to install it both local & global)
5. npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular
6. npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular
7. ng update --all
8. If you have ViewChild on your application, be sure to edit them with: [Source](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14553#issuecomment-497883378)

(Solution from https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14546)

Comment: Ok, but I am using asp.net core 2.2